# Send value from Blazor child component to parent without the child being reinitialised

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

Is it possible for a Blazor server child component to tell its parent that something has occurred without the child component being reinitialized? My parent page has a search form on it. There are two child components that give the results of the search. When the child component is initialized a method on that component is called to highlight bits of the data in the page.

There are click events on the child component to call the same highlight method on specific rows of the user's choosing. That highlight method calls back to the parent page to let it know if certain conditions are met. (It sends a bool back).

My problem is that because the method is called on the child component initialize, I get stuck in an infinite loop because the call black calls the parent which in turn then recreates the child.

I feel that conceptually I am doing something wrong. I want the child to literally call back the bool without the parent having to recreate the child.

Is this even possible?

Comment: It would be helpful to see some code snippets to make it easier for people to understand your problem. Typically you would use an `EventCallback` to notify a parent of some event, but it's hard to advise without seeing a concrete example of your current approach

Comment: "Is it possible for a blazor server child component to tell its parent that something has occured without the child component being reinitialised? "  **YES**, of course it is.  [Polite] But without a [MRE] of what you are trying to achieve, that's it for an answer.  To go further would be pure guesswork.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so since I dont have much context Im gonna make some assumtions.

But for now theese are my Example Classes

Parent:

```
@page "/Par"

<div style="height: 100px; width: 100px; background: red;"  >
    <ChildType @bind-Notifier="_notifier"></ChildType>
    <button @onclick="Cl">Par</button>
</div>


@code {
    
    private bool _notifier;

    public void Cl()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Par"+_notifier);
    }

}
```

Child:

```
<div style="height: 50px; width: 50px; background: black;" @onclick="Cl">

</div>


@code {
    
    [Parameter]
    public bool Notifier { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<bool> NotifierChanged { get; set; }


    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        
        UpdateNotifier();
       

        base.OnInitialized();
    }

    async Task UpdateNotifier()
    {
        Notifier = !Notifier;
        await NotifierChanged.InvokeAsync(Notifier);
    }

    public void Cl()
    {
        UpdateNotifier();
        Console.WriteLine("OnClick"+Notifier);
    }

}
```

And that could be it. If you try this example when you click on the black square(Child) the bool value should change without the Parent forcing the Child to Rerender, which can be confirmed via clicking on the button which should print the value available to parent.